# Is there any way to get the link from browser and when browser is opened using python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome

I want to have some python code which can read link from browser. When we open browser and when new link is opened. I want to keep track of which links are opened on my computer.

Comment: I think you should be able to create a Python script that would be able to poll your Chrome cache in order to fill some data of its own, for you to check stats later. Would that be enough?

Comment: How i can poll Chrome cache?

Comment: Chrome maintainers will know.